# MongoDB using with NodeJS

Tags: mongodb

I want to connect mongodb to nodejs.
I succeed to connect mongodb to nodejs but I can't access to mongodb Collection (test collection).

How can I use collection in my code?

```
BELOW MY CODE
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
var db;
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, database) {
   if (err) {
      console.error('MongoDB 연결 실패', err);
      return;
   }else{
    console.log("DB연결 성공")
   }
   
   db = database;
});
var movies = db.Collection('test');
movies.insert();

ERROR CODE
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Collection')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test\mongodbtest.js:15:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)       
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `db` instance sequentially, but the code in the callback will be executed after the `var movies = db.Collection('test');` line is called, so the variable won't be set.
You can either move the `insert` inside the callback:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, database) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('MongoDB 연결 실패', err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('DB연결 성공');
  }

  var movies = database.Collection('test');
  movies.insert();
});
```

Or use `async await`:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

const connectDb = async () => {
  try {
    return await MongoClient.connect(url)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('MongoDB 연결 실패', err);
  }
}

connectDb()
  .then((db) => {
    var movies = db.Collection('test');
    movies.insert();
  })
```

Comment: Hi! so Thank you to answer my question!!!